# Function comparing integers in C (pointers)

Tags: c, pointers, comparison, constants

Here's the following function which is supposed to compare the values of two integers `a` and `b` and return a positive number if `a>b` and a negative number otherwise:

```
 int int_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const int *ia = (const int*)a;
    const int *ib = (const int*)b;
    return *ia - *ib;
}
```

I am not too familiar with `constant` pointers (or pointers to `constant`s) and I do not really understand the reasoning behind the function above. I would appreciate it if someone could provide a step-by-step explanation.

Comment: well... this is not about pointers, this is just maths. If `a < b`, then `a - b < b - b = 0`, so this will return a negative number. Similarly, when `a > b`, then `a - b` will be positive, and if `a == b` then `a - b == 0`.

Comment: Your function should really be called `void_cmp` :P

Comment: @Moo-Juice Why? It's supposed to be comparing integers, no?

Comment: @H2CO3, it was somewhat tongue-in-cheek given it is *called* `int_cmp` but takes two `const void*` pointers :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice Aham :) well, since it is (should be) generic... (and C has no templates, unfortunately...)

Comment: Yes. There's a similar string_cmp function following up, hence the different notation.

Comment: @user112926 Also note that you should not cast pointers to `void`: consequently, `const int *ia = (const int*)a;` is not so good, while `const int *ia = a;` is.

Comment: `*ia - *ib` ： Note that you can use only in the range of limiting of type int.

Comment: @H2CO3, the idea of C with templates makes my left-eye twitch... ;)

Comment: @Moo-Juice Templates are one of the features why I even consider using C++ sometimes.

Comment: @H2CO3, oh I agree - I like them - for some reason the idea of them in C makes me nervous ;)

Comment: @Moo-Juice Ah OK. I personally think that "C with templates" would be a much better language than C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose, in the caller function, you have two int variables,

```
int p = 10;
int q = 5;
```

now , from your `main()` you are calling `int_cmp(&p, &q);` to compare their values.

in the receiving function `int_cmp()` the parameters are made `const` so that inside the `int_cmp()` function, the values of `int p` and `int q` should not be changed. If the values of `a` and/or `b` is changed in the `int_cmp()`, they will be changed in the `main()` also, as they have been passed using reference. so, to keep the values unchanged, the `const` is used.

Next, once the parameters are received in `int_cmp()`, they are typecasted to `int` as the arithmetic operators can be safely allowed on pointers of defined variable type.

I hope the atithmatic part is quite straightforward. It is de-referencing the pointers and calculating the difference between the values of the pointers `a` and `b` and returning the value of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this method is used in more general callback that expects a function pointer of the following type

```
int (*)(const void*, const void*)
```

This is the only reason I can see to use `const void*` here instead of `const int*`.

The reason for const is that comparison should be an operation that reads data only.  It shouldn't have any need to mutate the parameters in order to compare them.  Hence the standard definition of compare takes `const` data to encourage implementers to have the correct behavior